# Can't switch off RewriteRule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lamp

My **.htaccess** is:

```
RewriteEngine Off
RewriteRule ^poezje$ poezje-main.php
RewriteRule ^404$ 404.php
RewriteRule ^inna$ inna3.php
```

In spite of `RewriteEngine Off`, the first and second rules are still working. But the third rule is off, as expected.

The first two rules I created yesterday and the third I added today.

I'm working on Debian 6.0 Squeeze, Apache 2.2 with virtual hosts, mod_userdir and mod_rewrite.

Comment: You should put that answer in an answer instead of putting it in your question.

Answer (score 1):

comment out the rules with a #

```
RewriteEngine Off
#RewriteRule ^poezje$ poezje-main.php
#RewriteRule ^404$ 404.php
#RewriteRule ^inna$ inna3.php
```

Comment: I've done it and it didn't help

Comment: i would make sure there is no other .htaccess in the parent and children directories and clear the browser cache just in case it is related to caching

Comment: there is no other .htaccess in entire public_html and I've already clear browser cache

Comment: have you restarted your server?